# download file from OneDrive using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client

Tags: development, sharepoint-online, visual-studio-2012, onedrive-for-business, win-form

I have a winforms application and I need to download files from a SharePoint OneDrive directory. Currently, given my code below, I am able to read the "Title" of the file, but I can't find anything to help me download the file using **Microsoft.SharePoint.Client** .

```
string username = "appuser@abcuseraccount.com";
String pwd = "x!@ex";

ClientContext context = new ClientContext("https://abcuser.sharepoint.com/Main/financial/");

SecureString password = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in pwd.ToCharArray())
{
    password.AppendChar(c);
}

context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, password);
context.ExecuteQuery();

List docs = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Financial Notes");
Web site = context.Web;
context.Load(site);
context.ExecuteQuery();

CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(100);
ListItemCollection items = docs.GetItems(query);

context.Load(items);
context.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (ListItem listItem in items)
{
    MessageBox.Show(listItem["Title"].ToString());
}
```

How can I download the files to my local drive (without using LiveAccount auth)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [File.OpenBinaryDirect method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.openbinarydirect(v=office.15).aspx) to downloads the specified file from a SharePoint site.

The following example demonstrates how to download file from a Library by providing its item Id.

Example

```
/// <summary>
/// Download file from a Library 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="context">CSOM context</param>
/// <param name="listTitle">List Title</param>
/// <param name="listItemId">List Item Id</param>
/// <param name="downloadPath">Download Path</param>
private static void DownloadFile(ClientContext context, string listTitle, int listItemId, string downloadPath)
{
    var list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
    var listItem = list.GetItemById(listItemId);
    context.Load(listItem, i => i.File);
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    var fileRef = listItem.File.ServerRelativeUrl;
    var fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(context, fileRef);
    var fileName = Path.Combine(downloadPath, listItem.File.Name);
    using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(fileName))
    {
        fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
    }
}
```

Example 2

```
private static void DownloadFile(ClientContext context, string listTitle, int listItemId, string downloadPath)
{
    var list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
    var listItem = list.GetItemById(listItemId);
    context.Load(listItem); 
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    var fileRef = (string)listItem["FileRef"];
    var fileLeafRef = (string)listItem["FileLeafRef"];
    var fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(context, fileRef);
    var fileDownloadPath = Path.Combine(downloadPath, fileLeafRef);
    using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(fileDownloadPath))
    {
         fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Vadim. When I try your solution, I get an error "List 'A Strong Password' does not exist at site with URL '"https://abcuser.sharepoint.com/Main/financial/'.  When I am on the OneDrive document page, and I click "Open menu dialog for selected item", the path displayed has additional directories example (https://abcuser.sharepoint.com/Main/financial/_layouts/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=%7BF6A94294-00D4-4F36-9EDF-F83FB%7D&file=strong%20pwd.pdf&action=default

Comment: I am new to Sharepoint, so how would I get the path, it's likely that other files will have different directory paths.

Comment: Make sure you are specifying the correct site, for example to download file from Documents library located on site "https://consoto-my.sharepoint.com/personal/mysite" you is supposed to create ClientContext by passing that url and then call DownloadFile method by passing Library title  and List Item Id.

Comment: The site is correct, since I am able to get the TITLE of the documents, and when I hover over the "foreach (ListItem listItem in items)" I am getting the correct # of documents in the array.

Comment: I agree,in that case please make sure the correct list item id is passed.

Comment: list item id value is correct as well

Comment: the code throws an exception at " context.ExecuteQuery();" in the DownloadFile fucntion.

Comment: sure, i just updated the answer with alternative version (via FileRef)

Comment: could you please specify what kind of exception?

Comment: "Strong Pwd" is the Title. The error message is ""List 'Strong Pwd' does not exist at site with URL '"abcuser.sharepoint.com/Main/financial/"

Comment: when I do "Add Watch" on i.File, I get "The name 'i' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: But in your example "Financial Notes" is the title of the Library. I'm a little bit confused since you and me use the same method for getting list: List docs = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("<list title>");

Comment: yes, "Financial Notes" is the title of the library.

Comment: Okey, then please pass the proper library title to DownloadFile method, for example: DownloadFile(context,"Financial Notes",itemId,pathToDownload);

Comment: Good to know :)

Comment: unfortunately I don't have the rep points to upvote your answer .... will upvote soon as I can