# Getting Minor Version, Major Version, TimeCreated, TimeModified of document using CSOM

Tags: development, sharepoint-online, visual-studio-2012, onedrive-for-business, win-form

As a follow up to [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/111685/32419), I have a document that I am downloading from OneDrive library using CSOM.

```
private static void DownloadFile(ClientContext context, string listTitle, int listItemId, string downloadPath)
{
    var list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
    var listItem = list.GetItemById(listItemId);
    context.Load(listItem, i => i.File);
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    var fileRef = listItem.File.ServerRelativeUrl;
    var fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(context, fileRef);
    var fileName = Path.Combine(downloadPath, listItem.File.Name);
    using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(fileName))
    {
        fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
    }
}
```

Along with the document, I also need to get the document's Major Version, Minor Version, Modified by values etc. However, any code that I have found, only gives me "The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested" when I attempt to get the value from `File.ListItemAllFields` property.

How can I access those values?

**EDIT:**  Based on this post [The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/42629/32419) when I try

```
var listItemCollection = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
```

[image]

I can see the values in the Add Watch window. The fields in red are the ones I need to access (along with Version).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if this helps anyone, this code returns the values I needed.

```
List listFields = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Financial Notes");
context.Load(listFields);
context.Load(listFields.ContentTypes);
context.Load(listFields.Fields);
ListItem item;
// this is how you can get the item(file), you can also use CAML query
context.Load(item = listFields.GetItemById(listItemId));
//here you can get the dictonary for fieldvalue
context.Load(item.FieldValuesAsText);
context.ExecuteQuery();

//CreatedBy
string sCreatedBy = item.FieldValuesAsText["Created_x0020_By"];
//ModifiedBy
string modifiedBy = item.FieldValuesAsText["Modified_x0020_By"];
//TimeCreated
string sTimeCreated = item.FieldValuesAsText["Created_x0020_Date"];
//TimeModified
string sTimeModified = item.FieldValuesAsText["Last_x0020_Modified"];
//_CheckinComment
string sCheckinComment = item.FieldValuesAsText["_CheckinComment"];
//Title
string sTitle = item.FieldValuesAsText["Title"];
//MetaData Type
string sMetaDataType = item.FieldValuesAsText["Financial_x0020_Notes_x0020_Type"];

//Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue UserValue = 
string sUserValue = ((FieldUserValue)listItem["Author"]).LookupValue;
TaxonomyFieldValue taxFieldValue = item["Metadata"] as TaxonomyFieldValue;
```

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs since requested properties have not been loaded. You have to explicitly specify them in [ClientRuntimeContext.Load method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee536388(v=office.15).aspx).

Since you are getting `ListItemAllFields` property, you have to specify like this:

```
context.Load(listItem, i => i.File,i => i.File.ListItemAllFields);
```

Example 1

In order to retrieve `File` object with all `List Item` properties you could use the following code:

```
var list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
var listItem = list.GetItemById(listItemId);
context.Load(listItem, i => i.File,i => i.File.ListItemAllFields);
context.ExecuteQuery();
Console.WriteLine(listItem.File.ListItemAllFields.FieldValues["Modified_x0020_By"]);
```

Example 2

There is a better way to retrieve File properties. 
The following example demonstrates how to load `File` object associated with `List Item` and print its properties:

```
var list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
var listItem = list.GetItemById(listItemId);
context.Load(listItem, i => i.File);
context.ExecuteQuery();
//print file properties
Console.WriteLine(listItem.File.ModifiedBy.LoginName);
Console.WriteLine(listItem.File.MajorVersion);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help again Vadim. I am getting an error at "File.ModifiedBy.LoginName". The error is ""The property or field 'LoginName' has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested."

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to retrieve the properties? If yes, then you will find it within your SPListItem -> listItem["Modified_x0020_By"], etc.. But not all of them. Via listItem.File.Versions you get a collection of the file versions which you can iterate through respectively can read the properties e.g. "Level" (Draft, Published...) or "VersionLabel" (-> version number) of each file version.

Please, let me know if this is what you have wanted to know.

Comment: Yes, I am looking to get the values from listItem.File object